# Procedimiento obtiene una excepción este correcto o no

Tags: stored-procedure, plsql, excepciones

Hola estoy haciendo un procedimiento para la lectura de un archivo usando utl_file ahora intento colocar excepciones por ejemplo si el archivo esta vacío o no existe pero las excepciones son lanzadas incluso cuando la ejecución fue correcta

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.leer (p_file_name   IN     VARCHAR2,
                                       p_linea       OUT    CLOB,
                                       p_errbuf      OUT    VARCHAR2)
AS
   v_file   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   v_line   VARCHAR2 (32000);
   my_arr   v_arr1 := v_arr1 ();
   v_path   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'HR_DIR_HDL';
BEGIN
   v_file :=
      UTL_FILE.FOPEN (v_path,
                      p_file_name,
                      'R',
                      32767);

   BEGIN
      LOOP
         UTL_FILE.GET_LINE (v_file, v_line);
         my_arr.EXTEND;
         my_arr (my_arr.COUNT) := v_line;
      END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
         p_errbuf := 'Error de lectura. No se Encontraron Datos.';
         --p_retcode := 1;
         utl_file.fclose (l_file);
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN                              
         UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (v_file);
   END;

   FOR i IN 1 .. my_arr.COUNT
   LOOP
      p_linea := p_linea || chr(10) || my_arr(i);
   END LOOP;
END leer;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

La excepción `NO_DATA_FOUND` salta cuando se llega al final del archivo y `UTL_FILE.GET_LINE` no puede leer más líneas. No significa que hubo un error. ¿Cómo saldrías del loop, si no?

Si querés comprobar si el archivo estaba o no vacío, podés verificar que `my_arr.COUNT` no sea `0`.